# How to update a particular column of a row in a csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I am having a csv file with the following contents

```
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
w,x,y,z
```

And i want to update this csv file contents to

```
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d,k
w,x,y,z
```

Can someone please share Python code for this update process??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the csv library, we read in the data, convert it to a list of lists, append the k to the relevant list, then write it out again.

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open("input.csv"))

l = list(data)    
l[1].append("k")

our_writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))

our_writer.writerows(l)
```

While the csv library isn't completely necessary for your toy case, it's often good to use the approach that scales well.

Comment: For generality you might find `with` statement helpful to close the files properly. To update the file inplace you could write to a temporary file and rename it on success. You should use `'wb'` mode for the output file. If you load all rows in memory then `writer.writerows()` allows you to write all the rows at once.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `csv` for such a simple case:

```
# sed '2s/$/,k/'
import fileinput
for lineno, line in enumerate(fileinput.input(inplace=True), start=1):
    if lineno == 2:
       line = line.rstrip('\n') + ",k\n"
    print line,
```

Example:

```
$ python update_2nd_line.py data_to_update.csv
```

It updates `data_to_update.csv` file inplace.